# Frozen discard pile

Tags: canasta

When picking up a frozen discard pile I understand that you have to have a natural pair in your hand, but can I add those cards to a meld in play in front of me to create a canasta?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, once you have picked up the discard pile, the cards are all in your hand like normal; and you can always add to any existing meld by melding more cards from your hand. Whether the discard pile was frozen or not does not have any relevance here.

> A player may add additional cards to a meld by his side, provided that the melds remain valid (having no more than three wild cards). He may not add cards to the opponents' melds.

https://www.bicyclecards.com/how-to-play/canasta/

Comment: You're welcome. On Stack Exchange; the best way to thank someone is to vote the answer up if you found it useful, and click the check to accept it if it's the best one. Sometimes it's useful to wait a little bit before accepting an answer to see if other people answer as well.